# Error permission denied through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

I connected to bastion-staging (ftp server-name) through `ssh` (from local machine).
I have get access through `sudo bash`.

Now I am trying to `ssh` from bastion-staging (myserver-name) to ecash (another-server).

But when I run:

```
ssh root@ecash
```

I get an error:

```
          WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0777 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Moreover, I have no password for ecash , I've been said I could ssh as root to another server (e.g ecash).

What should I do now?

Comment: `Permissions 0777 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.` <===

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the file? Or better: if this is a copy of the same key (because you trust the remote) then use `ssh -A`. And why become root?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fix the permissions for the file indicated in the error message (running the following as root):

```
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The `id_rsa` contains a private key required, in your case, to connect to the `ecash` server. It should be protected from access by unauthorised accounts (much like the password).

Having `777` permissions to the means, however, the file is readable by anyone and SSH refuses to use the file. Changing the permissions to `600` makes the file readable and writable by the owner (root) account only which is a minimal requirement for `ssh` command to use the file.